# Analytical approximate solution to a trascendental equation

Tags: roots, approximation, error-function

I have the following equation to solve
$$
z+e^{z^2}\operatorname{erfc}(z)=0
$$
being
$$
\operatorname{erfc}(z)=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ze^{-s^2}ds.
$$
I solved it numerically and appears to have an infinity of complex solutions. I am in need to find an approximate analytical approximation for the first root. I made several attempts, e.g. using either Taylor or asymptotic expansions, but to no avail. I was not able to recover the first root that seems to be $-.3378723369\ldots-.9499598705\ldots i$.

My question: is it possible to find a successful approximation scheme to get an analytical expression for the roots of the given equation?

**Edit:** There appear to be infinite roots in $\mathbb{C}$. This can be seen straightforwardly in Fig. 1 where both the real and imaginary part are given of $-z$ and $e^{z^2}\operatorname{erfc}(z)$
[image: Fig. 1]

Orange is $Re(-z)$, green is $Im(-z)$. There is a common line between this twos crossing the part with the erfc showing a possible infinite set of roots.

I was able to find several roots by choosing a different starting point for the search algorithm. E.g. I have got, listing just a few along with their complex conjugates implied,

$-1.90593 - 1.82833 i$

$-3.19368 - 3.06637 i$

$-4.07604 - 3.94595 i$

$-6.71931 - 6.60297 i$

$-8.00551 - 7.89692 i$

$-10.2496 - 10.1527 i$

The aforementioned first root appears a recurring one in the search.

Comment: Please, have a look to my edit. I do not think that the equations has many roots. Did you find other solutions ? If you did, please tell me. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici From the plot I made with Mathematica, it seemed to me that the number of roots was large. E.g. I also get $-5.114532877548192 + 4.9884679626263475i$ and finding or not another root depends on the starting point in FindRoot.. I think you can easily check by yourself that the one I showed you is another zero.

Comment: Have a look to my edit. Using the contour plot of $\Phi(x,y)=1$, I had to zoom crazy to "see" the solution you reported in your last comment (in fact, I did not see it - my wife did it for me !). I wonder if we could face some accuracy problems here with $\Phi(x,y)$,

Comment: Well, I plotted the imaginary and real part in a 3d plot and drawn the x and y plans. It is seen in this way that there seems to be a multitude of roots. Maybe, a contour plot could be not so easy to read. I used FindRoot starting from $-5-5i$ and the root come out.

Comment: Good to know that ! It would be good you list in the post some of the roots. I am sure that you know that if $(a+ib)$ is a root $(a-ib)$ is another one.

Comment: Yes, I know. As time permits I will update my question as you ask.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Update done. I hope this will make clear my thinking.

Comment: There is something funny I just found before your answer came. I shall edit.

Comment: For the fun of it, build the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant and solve for $z$. It would be better (I bet). I think that you have something very interesting. Cheers & thanks for the problem 'I had a lot of fun with it !). :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the first root using Newton method.

Using for example $z_0=1+i$, it would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & z_n \\
 0 & 1+ i \\
 1 & -0.570752+0.455687 i \\
 2 & -0.217277+0.691623 i \\
 3 & -0.298698+1.012267 i \\
 4 & -0.336117+0.946645 i \\
 5 & -0.337868+0.949970 i \\
 6 & -0.337872+0.949960 i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $z_0=1-i$, it would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & z_n \\
 0 & 1-i \\
 1 & -0.570752-0.455687 i \\
 2 & -0.217277-0.691623 i \\
 3 & -0.298698-1.012267 i \\
 4 & -0.336117-0.946645 i \\
 5 & -0.337867-0.949968 i \\
 6 & -0.337872-0.949960 i 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Starting with $z_0=i$ seems to converge  faster
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & z_n \\
 0 & i \\
 1 & -0.400169+0.909374 i \\
 2 & -0.339614+0.946181 i \\
 3 & -0.337864+0.949950 i \\
 4 & -0.337872+0.949960 i
\end{array}
\right)$$

The same starting with $z_0=-i$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & z_n \\
 0 & - i \\
 1 & -0.400169-0.909374 i \\
 2 & -0.339614-0.946181 i \\
 3 & -0.337864-0.949950 i \\
 4 & -0.337872-0.949960 i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Concerning approximations, I am stuck. The only thing I really tried is a series expansion around $z=i$ and got
$$\frac{-i \text{erfi}(1)+1+i e}{e}+\frac{\left(2 \text{erfi}(1)+2 i+e-\frac{2
   e}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) (z-i)}{e}+\frac{\left(i \text{erfi}(1)-1-\frac{2 i
   e}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) (z-i)^2}{e}+O\left((z-i)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, solving the quadratic in $(z-i)$ and evaluating leads to $$z\approx -0.351584 + 0.947053 i$$ Doing the same around $z=-i$ gives the other root.

**Edit**

In terms of approximation of the solution, we can do better using the simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant built at $z_\pm=\pm i$. For example,
$$z_+=-\frac{i \left(-4 e \left(\pi -2 \sqrt{\pi }\right) (\text{erfi}(1)+i)-5 \pi 
   (\text{erfi}(1)+i)^2+4 e^2 \left(\sqrt{\pi }-1\right)\right)}{e \left(5 \pi -6
   \sqrt{\pi }\right) (\text{erfi}(1)+i)+3 \pi  (\text{erfi}(1)+i)^2+e^2 \left(4-6
   \sqrt{\pi }+\pi \right)}$$ which is $-0.347274 + 0.955038 i$ much better than the previous one.

We could continue with $[1,n]$ Padé approximant to get explicit approximations (the expressions are really messy). The values are reporteds below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & z^{(n)}_+\\
 0 &  -0.400169+0.909374 i \\
 1 &  -0.347274+0.955038 i \\
 2 &  -0.337395+0.951302 i \\
 3 &  -0.337591+0.949901 i \\
 4 &  -0.337859+0.949907 i
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

Looking at the table of the roots given in Jon' edit, they really look like $z_k \sim -k \pm ki$. Using  the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant built at $z=-k-ik$ (the formula is too messy to be reported here) an approximation of the root can be obtained.

Below are listed some values (to be compared to Jon's)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & -0.34995-0.95803 i \\
 2 & -1.90291-1.81163 i \\
 3 & -3.23300-3.00433 i \\
 4 & -4.06884-3.94940 i \\
 5 & -5.10001-4.96837 i \\
 6 & -6.05119-5.85692 i \\
 7 & -7.09451-6.88121 i \\
 8 & -8.03695-7.91822 i \\
 9 & -9.07841-8.95282 i \\
 10 & -10.0648-9.96230 i \\
 11 & -11.0449-10.9348 i \\
 12 & -12.0518-11.9671 i \\
 13 & -13.0490-12.9660 i \\
 14 & -14.0285-13.9565 i \\
 15 & -15.0394-14.9589 i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very nice.

Comment: Very neat answer. This is what I needed. Thank you very much.